# AttributeError:'tensorflow.python.framework.fast_tensor_util' has no attribute 'appendfloat32arraytotensorproto'

Tags: tensorflow, attributeerror

TensorFlow 2.2.0 + Keras 2.3.1 on Python 3.7

How to fix this AttributeError? I reinstall the TensorFlow but it does not work.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had an exact same issue with **Python 3.5.6 :: Anaconda, Inc.** but I don't think it's Python's or TF version fault.

Frankly speaking, decided to **create a new py-env** like this (given that I use **conda** distro):

Created this `env.yml` file:

```
name: tf2
channels:
  - defaults
  - anaconda
dependencies:
  - jupyter
  - matplotlib
  - numpy
  - python=3.7
  - scikit-learn
  - tensorflow
```

then ran

```
conda env create -f env.yml 
conda activate tf2
python -m ipykernel install --user --name=tf2
jupyter notebook
```

and it all works:

[image]